# scanner.nextInt() returns java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java.util.scanner

This is my code, which is supposed to accept input from the user and set 2 int values. The exit function works correctly however when the input string is "5 2" for example, it sets x as 5 and throws the java.util.NoSuchElementException at the y = s2.nextInt(); line, even though there is a next int. In an example of nextInt() I saw, ints were seperated by a space and the scanner still picked up all the integers. Is mine missing something?

```
String exit = "-1";
Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = s1.next();
Scanner s2 = new Scanner(input);
if (input.equals(exit))
    Sequence.quit();
else {  
    x = s2.nextInt();
    y = s2.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you print out your variable `ìnput`, you will see that it contains only "5" - since `s1.next()` wil stop at space.

Something like this:

```
String exit = "-1";
Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);
int x  = s1.nextInt();
if (x==-1) 
    Sequence.quit();
else {  
    y = s1.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: I see. I scrolled through the Scanner class and found that changing input = s2.next(); to input = s2.nextLine(); solved the problem